# Typegoose ref with array of subdocuments

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, typegoose

I'm trying to get nested subdocuments array using Typegoose.

Before refactoring with Typegoose, I had this working code with mongoose :

Interface :

```
export interface IFamily extends Document {
    name: string;
    products: IProduct[];
}
```

Schema :

```
const familySchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }]
});
```

When I did Family.findById('5f69aa0a56ca5426b44a86c5'), I had an array of Product ObjectId in my JSON result.

After refoctoring, I use Typegoose :

Class :

```
@modelOptions({ schemaOptions: { collection: 'families' } })
export class Family {
    
    @prop({ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId })
    public _id?: string;
    @prop({ type: String, required: false })
    public name?: string;
    @prop({ ref: () => Product, required: true, default: [] })
    public products!: Product[];
}
```

When I do :

```
getModelForClass(Family).findById('5f69aa0a56ca5426b44a86c5')
```

property "products" with an array of ObjectId is not in the result (property is absent) :

```
{
  "_id": "5f69aa0a56ca5426b44a86c5",
  "name": "Fourniture"
}
```

I can't figue how to make that working. I think the problem is in the family class @prop(ref). I saw some example where peoples used @arrayProp but now is deprecated.

I find documentation about ref with a simple object but not with an array of object with version 5.9.1 of Typegoose.

Thanks

Comment: you should upgrade to typegoose 7.4, anything below 7.0 dosnt support `type: () =>` (or ref)

Answer (score 0):

aside from using an old version of typegoose with new "syntax"
this is how it is supposed to look in typegoose (7.4)

```
@modelOptions({ schemaOptions: { collection: 'families' } })
export class Family {
    @prop()
    public _id?: string;

    @prop()
    public name?: string;

    @prop({ ref: () => Product, required: true, default: [] })
    public products!: Ref<Product>[]; // if Product's "_id" is also "string", then it would need to be ": Ref<Product, string>[];"
}
```